# jquery htmlbox 4.0 onblur event

Tags: jquery-plugins

How can i catch the "onblur" event of my htmlbox textarea? 
I want to be able to get the htmlbox content when it's onblur..

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it loops waiting 1 second until htmlbox creates the iframe, then it adds a .blur handler to the iframe, I found out the iframe's id by using IE8's Developer Tools, by clicking on the arrow icon in the developer tools and clicking the box you can see how HTML looks after the page loads and javascript processed. if($("iframe").length) is true then then htmlbox has created the iframe and you can attach the .blur event handler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var check = function(){
            if($("iframe").length){
                $("#hb_html").blur(function(){
                    alert('Blur has occurred!');
                });
            } else {
                setTimeout(check, 1000)
            }
        }
        setTimeout(check, 1000)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank's!! do you know if there is a way to disable the htmlbox textarea?

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrates:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#bar").blur(function(){
        $(this).text("I have been blurred.");
    });
});
</script>

<textarea id='bar'>foo</textarea>
```

**Make sure the file jquery-1.5.min.js is in the same folder IF you use the example above.**

You can read up on the .blur event at http://api.jquery.com/blur/

It receives a function as an argument and executes it when it becomes blurred.

Comment: thank's for you reply, but this does not work for me, i tried it in my code , and even in htmlbox example and also there it did not wotk.. any idea why? it seems as it does treats the htmlbox textarea as regular textarea..